# When can BlockingCollection<T> TryTake() return false?

Tags: c#, collections, concurrency

Assuming the BlockingCollection is using a ConcurrentQueue underneath, when could the [TryTake(T, Int32) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287154%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) return false if you are using Timeout.Infinite?

Comment: The document you linked to contains the answer to your question. What are you looking for in an answer? A concrete example? Code that will fail? The docs clearly state what will cause the method to throw.

Comment: Or, instead, are you asking when it would return `false` instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: @ledbutter That is what I am asking, I have updated the OP.

Comment: @elgonzo So in this case there is not a situation in which it would return false barring the listed exceptions in the msdn link?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a simple example that shows when it can return false: when the collection is marked as `CompleteAdding` and becomes emptу

```
//by default, BlockingCollection will use ConcurrentQueue
BlockingCollection<int> coll = new BlockingCollection<int>();

coll.Add(1);
coll.Add(2);
coll.CompleteAdding();

int item;

if (coll.TryTake(out item, -1))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

if (coll.TryTake(out item, -1))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

if (coll.TryTake(out item, -1))
{
    //this won't get hit
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("TryTake returned false!");
}
```

This allows you to forbid adding new items in queue and complete processing of remaining elements

Comment: If you do not trigger with .CompleteAdding(), it will not return false though, correct?

Comment: @Gyrien correct, but it won't ever get past the last `TryTake` call (assuming you use an infinite timeout) as it will wait there until you signal that you are done adding to the collection.

Answer (score 7):

This will print `false` :

```
 var coll = new BlockingCollection<int>();            

 coll.CompleteAdding();   // closed for business

 int v;
 bool result = coll.TryTake(out v, Timeout.Infinite);

 Console.WriteLine(result);
```

So basically a BlockingCollection supports 2 separate concepts: Empty and Closed. And while TryTake() can wait forever on an Empty queue, when the queue is both Empty *and* Closed it will return `false`.

Comment: If you do not trigger with .CompleteAdding(), it will not return false though, correct?