# BlockingCollection TryTake returns false instead of block when the collection is empty

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, blockingcollection

I get back false from BlockingCollection's **TryTake** method, when the **BlockingCollection** is empty, although the expected behavior is to block until the collection fills up.

Note that the collection is not upper bounded (which should affect the TryAdd not the TryTake) and that the Timeout set for the add operation had not passed.

Here's my wrapper around the BlockingCollection object:

```
    public T TryTake(int timeoutMiliseconds)
    {
        var result = default(T);

        if (!_collection.TryTake(out result, timeoutMiliseconds))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to get item from collection.");
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Any ideas what can cause this ?

I've implemented the Producer-Consumer pattern, based on this article:
[Multithread processing of the SqlDataReader - Producer/Consumer design pattern](http://dzapart.blogspot.co.il/2014/12/multithread-processing-of-sqldatareader.html)

Comment: What does the *message* included with the exception say?

Comment: I've added it to the post

Comment: `TryTake` does not throw this exception because collection it empty, it throws it for other reasons (described in documentation of this method)

Comment: For the benefit of others, the method being called in the code above is NOT `BlockingCollection<T>.TryTake`.  It is a method of a custom class that, internally, calls `BlockingCollection<T>.TryTake` and throws the specified exception if an item cannot be taken within the specified timeout period. Follow the link provided to see that code. I did and realised that my answer wasn't applicable.

Comment: As @jmcilhinney mentions this exception is literally thrown in the `TryTake` method you copy pasted from your link. At least read code you are copy pasting, or use a debugger which would point you right at the code throwing that exception.

Comment: The exception is documented well, it tells you that the code that adds items to the collection has a bug.  It is not doing it in a thread-safe way.  We can't see it.

Comment: You're right guys, I got confused between the original collection TryTake and the wrapping TryTake. But the fact is that the TryTake returns false instead of block on the TryTake. I guess that's because the `CompleteAdding` is marked true like in this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195224/when-can-blockingcollectiont-trytake-return-false. I'm verifying it.

Answer (score -1):

I finally realized that as this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195224/when-can-blockingcollectiont-trytake-return-false/21195735) demonstrates, I got false out of `TryTake` cause the collection had been emptied, and also marked by me as completed (by calling `CompleteAdding()` method upon the collection).

So in order to solve it, I've added a condition on the completed flag.

One can argue that `TryTake` would never return **false** while the completed flag is **false**. I'm not sure that's always right, so I prefer to throw an error in this case.

```
    public T TryTake(int timeoutMiliseconds)
    {
        var result = default(T);

        if (!_collection.TryTake(out result, timeoutMiliseconds) 
            && !_collection.IsAddingCompleted)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to get item from collection.");
        }

        return result;
    }
```

NOTE that it's crucial to put the `TryTake` call first and the `IsAddingCompleted` second. Otherwise the first condition might pass and you'd block on the `TryTake` right after.

Comment: Could there be a race condition here, TryTake can return false, and then the collection is marked as completed, before you check IsAddingCompleted?

Comment: Could be. But a Consumers use this method to take out items inserted by the producer, so in the case you've described, another consumer would have taken the item before the current consumer in your scenario.. which is ok.

Comment: Except that you will get back `default(T)`?

Comment: Yes. The user of this function should be aware of the possibility to get a default(T) which is in practice null, in most cases.